# vue + firestore: how to bind / merge data with vuefire?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

I have a cloud firestore with data structured this way:

```
baskets

    basket 1
        basketID
        userID
        description
        products
            productID
            productID
    basket 2
        basketID
        userID
        description
        products
            productID
            productID
    ...
    basket N

products

    product A
        productID
        description
        productImg
        price
    product B
        productID
        description
        productImg
        price
    ...
    product Z
```

This structure in order to avoid duplicating detailed product data inside each basket document.

I created a vue component to display at once both the basket data and the products data associated to the basket, while trying to limit and optimize firebase queries. I have sucessfully binded the basket data like this:

```
  data() {
    return {
      basket: [],
      basket_products: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$bind('basket', db.collection("baskets").where("basketID", "==", this.basketID))
  }
```

However I'm struggling to bind the `basket_products` data for the current basket. I'm looking for something like this:

```
    this.$bind('basket_products', db.collection("products").where("productID", 'in', ONE OF THE PRODUCT_IDS WITHIN CURRENT BASKET, EQUIVALENT TO this.basket[0].products))
```

Comment: Are the productIDs in the basket strings or references? And if they are string, could you store firestore references instead?

Comment: productIDs are stored as strings

Comment: @ThomasKuhlmann I've stored references instead, now I get the associated product data in the `basket` object. I think that's exactly what I was looking for, I was not familiar with references yet. Thank you for your help ;-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad my pointer helped!

Just for completeness sake - the best solution as mentioned is to simply store references, vuefire automatically picks up on those and saves them accordingly as part of the baskets thanks to the `maxRefsDepth` option.

Aside from that, you could potentially play around with the [serialize option of vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuefire.html#options-serialize) to modify (and query additional) data when getting the baskets.

But this would be fairly complex, you might be better off just manually subscribing using the firebase SDK instead.